# entity framework 4 and NOT using ESQL

Tags: frameworks, entity-framework-4, entity-sql

Starting to play around with EF4 and I notice there are several different ways to query the DB.

Currently I created an .EDMX with my tables/objects created.

In code when I use the `Where` method, it wants me to pass in a string for the 1st param, ESQL I'm guessing. What I want to use is lambda expressions. All the tutorials show this, but isn't how I'm setup for some reason.

```
new Entities().Users.Where();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you must include the namespace System.Linq to get the extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your user entity has a property called LastName, you would write something like this to get all users with the

```
Entities().Users.Where(u => u.LastName == "Hansen");
```